# Selecting distinct with certain condition

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, t-sql, lambda

I have values in a list:

```
List1
ID    groupID   testNo
1     123       0
2     653       1
3     776       6
4     653       0
```

I want to write a T-Sql or linq or lambda expression, so that whenever there is a duplicate it should pick the one with value !=0

I am using this expression but it is basically not giving the results I want.

```
 var list2 = list1.GroupBy(x => x.testNo).Select(y => y.First());
```

How can I get the results so groupID 653 is chosen with testNo 1 with rest of the records?

Comment: Is it possible to have triplicates as well or just duplicates?

Comment: No just duplicates only.

Comment: you mean 'whenever there is a duplicate groupID it should pick the one with testNo!=0'? If so, please edit your question to clarify

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should give you the desired results:

```
var list2 = list1.GroupBy(x => x.groupID)
                 .Select(x => list1.Single(item => item.groupID == x.Key
                              && item.testNo == x.Max(y => y.testNo)))
                 .ToList();
```

Basically, group by `groupID` and then select each item from the original `list1` that matches the distinct `groupID` and has the max value for `testNo` for that `groupID`.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few approaches you could take. I don't know if any of them are full proof. One would be to do an `OrderBy` on `testNo` so that items with a non zero `testNo` will come up before those with 0.

```
var list2 = list1.Orderby(y => y.testNo).GroupBy(x => x.testNo).Select(z => z.FirstOrDefault());
```

If you can guarantee that `testNo = 0` only occurs for dupes then the easiest way is just to use a where.

```
var list2 = list1.Where(x => x.testNo > 0).First();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 var result = list.GroupBy(x => x.groupID).Select(g => g.Count() == 1 ? g.First() : g.First(x => x.testNo != 0));
```